# Are these example subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

**Example 1**

The subgroup $\{0,3\}$ of $\mathbb Z_6$ is a normal subgroup

I know it's a subgroup because the element $3\in\mathbb Z_6$ generates $\{0,3\}$ under addition

$\langle 3\rangle=(0,3)$ and the order is $2$ since we are back to the identity. But is it normal? I don't know how to prove/disprove it.

**Example 2**

The subgroup $\{e,h\}$ where $h$ is a reflection of $D_3$ is a normal subgroup.

Normally I would check if $\frac{|G|}{|H|}=2$ to show they are normal.

Comment: Please look at my edits.  $<3>$ is not standard notation; $\langle 3\rangle$ is. And in $\{0,3\}$ I've put the curly braces _inside_ the math tags (with a backslash on each) rather than outside, so you don't get mismatches in font size and lack of proper spacing, as in {$0,3$}.  Also I changed $Z$ to $\mathbb Z$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Hint:$Z_6$ is an abelian group !

Comment: Okay, So I can just use the theorem that says If $Z_6$ is abelian -> every subgroup of G is normal.

Comment: what about the second part, since $D_3$ is not abelian. Suppose H={e.h}. Then $ghg^{-1}$ does not equal to $h$ or $e$, thus it's not normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual test for normality of a subgroup $H \leq G$ is to check one of the following:

\begin{align*}gH = Hg \text{ for all }g \in G &\iff gHg^{-1} \subseteq H \text{ for all }g \in G \\
&\iff ghg^{-1} \in H \text{ for all }g \in G\text{ and }h \in H.\end{align*}

Of course, in an abelian group, the computations are all quite nice (for example, what is $ghg^{-1}$, only knowing that $g$ and $h$ belong to an abelian group?).

The result that $H \lhd G$ whenever $\lvert G : H\rvert = 2$ is a nice easy test for normality, but it too stems from the above criteria. You should keep the description *normal subgroups are precisely those fixed by conjugation* in mind.

If you're claiming that Example $2$ above is actually a normal subgroup, you should re-think that. Recall that $D_3 \cong S_3$, and think about what happens when you conjugate a $2$-cycle by anything.

Comment: What do you mean by conjugate a 2-cycle? Either e goes to h, or it remains an identity. But I don't really understand the point of that.

Comment: I do understand that normal subgroups are a union of the same conjugacy classes, that is if they have the same cycle type

Comment: I mean, let's say our reflection corresponds to $(1 2) \in S_3$, so that $ \langle (1 2) \rangle = \{e, (1 2)\}$. Then (depending on notation conventions) we can calculate, for example, $(1 2 3)(1 2)(1 2 3)^{-1} = (23) \not\in \langle (1 2) \rangle$. That means we found some group element that *doesn't* fix $\langle (1 2) \rangle$, and so it can't be normal in $S_3 \cong D_3$. The $2$-cycles in $S_3$ correspond to flips in $D_3$.